# onClick Navigation in React.js for Icons

Tags: reactjs

I have a component  which I want an icon to navigate to when it is clicked. The icon is present in an item tray as below.

```
  items = [
        {
          label: "Approve",
          Icon: <Checkmark/>,
          path:                //<SideLayer/> should be invoked from here
        },
        {
          label: "Reject",
          Icon: <Dislike/>,
          path: "/Dashboard"
        },
        {
          label: "Request Info",
          Icon: <Revert/>,
          path: "/History"
        }
      ];
```

SideLayer is an overlayer component and I do not want to go to any new page, the layer should get rendered on the same page. I have tried using "onCLick" and "onPress" instead of path but on clicking the icon, nothing works, there is no navigation. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How is this `items` array used? The code included at the moment doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: I could not get what you are trying to do. Can you add some more code , screenshots and minimal reproducing code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <ActionBar items={items}/>  @DBS

Comment: The items tray contains more icons that are displayed in a different component, I want to handle the functionality of one of those icons in the items array using the SideLayer/ @DBS

Comment: It sounds like the navigation takes place inside this `ActionBar` component, if that's a custom component then I would suggest including it in the question, if it's part of a library,  you may need to look at the documentation for that library (And preferably include the name/details of the library in the question)